# Child DataGrid not showing data

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

In trying to display two datagrid at the same time with one as parent & another as child. Problem here is child grid is not displayin any data. Here i am using same List class for Parent & Child class. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Here in the Parent grid i will be showing only 3 columns and rest of the columns i will be displaying it in Child Grid

Here is the sample code

```
<DataGrid Name="dgEmplist" ItemsSource="{Binding}"AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Id"  Binding="{Binding EmployeeId}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Name"  Binding="{Binding EmployeeName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status"  Binding="{Binding Status}" />                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <DataGrid Margin="40,10,0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGrid>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Parent and detail grid should display same list?

Comment: In the child grid I tried explicitly adding columns but it didn't work so marked AutoGenerateColumns="True"

Comment: The parent and the child grid have different DataContext. The Context of the child grid is the the parent Grid whereas the context of the parent grid is the context of the window. I hope I'm clear enough